# Running multiple stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, exec

I'm trying to run following code

```
USE [cp_mydatabse]
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SP_myProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = 'tempDB')
      EXEC SP_UpdatetempDB - copy data from another data base
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       print 'database does not exists'
       EXEC SP_CreatetempDB -- create my database SP
       EXEC SP_CreatetempDBTables - create table SP
       EXEC SP_UpdateTEmpDBData - copy data from another database
   END
```

If my `tempDB` exists, I figured out that code is running the `EXEC SP_CreatetempDB` as well. What is the reason for that ? But I cannot see

```
print 'database does not exists'
```

output on my console. Do you have any idea about this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SP_myProcedure]
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = 'tempDB') BEGIN
 EXEC SP_UpdatetempDB - copy data from another data base
END
ELSE BEGIN
  print 'database does not exists'
  EXEC SP_CreatetempDB -- create my database SP
  EXEC SP_CreatetempDBTables - create table SP
  EXEC SP_UpdateTEmpDBData - copy data from another database
END
```

Comment: Compare to the original: the `begin` was before the `if` part

Answer (score 0):

i am naive to sql server & database .....

i think

```
USE [cp_mydatabse]
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SP_myProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = 'tempDB')
BEGIN
EXEC SP_UpdatetempDB - copy data from another data base
END
ELSE
BEGIN
print 'database does not exists'
EXEC SP_CreatetempDB -- create my database SP
EXEC SP_CreatetempDBTables - create table SP
EXEC SP_UpdateTEmpDBData - copy data from another database
END
END
```

Should work